# find and replace xml syntax

Tags: notepad++

Trying to find and replace some xml syntax. Not quite sure how to add text after a certain line. I am adding a line after the < br> tag, but there are too many < br> so I am trying to specific it to the br after "Place".

Another situation where I need to remove the line, the beginning, the end and between.

**The Body**

```
< br>
place: < br>
Area: 1< br>
< br>
place: KITTE< br>
Area: 2< br>
```

- Case 1.

**FIND:** Place: *something* < br>

**REPLACE with:** Place: *something* < br>name: < br>

**FIND:** Place: < br>

**REPLACE with:** Place: < br>name: < br>

- Case 2.

**FIND:** Area: *something* < br>   OR  Area: < br>

delete this line

Comment: Please [edit] and include some real example text - before and after your required changes (one set for each of your cases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Case 1

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `^place: (.*)< br>`
- Set "Replace with" to `place: \1< br>name: < br>`
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

  [image]

**Before**:

```
< br>
place: < br>
Area: 1< br>
< br>
place: KITTE< br>
Area: 2< br>
```

**After**:

```
< br>
place: < br>name: < br>
Area: 1< br>
< br>
place: KITTE< br>name: < br>
Area: 2< br>
```

---

#### Case 2

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `^Area: (.*)< br>(?:\r?\n?|$)`
- Set "Replace with" to an empty string
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

  [image]

**Before**:

```
< br>
place: < br>name: < br>
Area: 1< br>
< br>
place: KITTE< br>name: < br>
Area: 2< br>
```

**After**:

```
< br>
place: < br>name: < br>
< br>
place: KITTE< br>name: < br>
```

---

#### Further reading

- [How to use regular expressions in Notepad++ (tutorial)](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)
- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
- [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: thank you very much, I still haven't got the change to try the answer, yet.